# Angular Firebase - Pull data from collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I simply want to pull a document from a firebase firestore collection using angular. I can't seem to find a simple explanation of how to do that? I have the "id" of the document that I wish to get.

I don't want to subscribe to an observable, I simply want to pull data one time. How do I do that?

Surely, somewhere there has to be documentation that explains how to use firebase with angular?

Comment: The linked question does not answer my question. It does not show what the "itemscollection" function is and it does not show what the "this" is in reference to.It makes no reference to any documentation and is 2.5 years old - meaning that it was obsolete a long time ago.

Comment: Using that answer, how do you specify the collection?
using that answer, how are you sure this is the proper method to do this and not merely a strung up way to do it?

Comment: Without seeing what you tried, it's unlikely someone will explain it better than the AngularFire documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/docs/firestore